# Check for specific text in Robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, yandex

My URL ends with `&content=Search`. I want to block all URLs that end with this. I have added following in robots.txt.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap: http://local.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://local.com/en/sitemap.xml
Disallow: /*&content=Search$
```

But it's not working when testing `/en/search?q=terms#currentYear=2015&content=search` in https://webmaster.yandex.com/robots.xml. It is not working for me because `content=search` is after `#` character.

Comment: How do you test/know that it’s not working?

Comment: @unor I tested it at "https://webmaster.yandex.com/robots.xml#results"

Comment: Testing `/foobar&content=Search` with this checker works for me: "blocked by rule `/*&content=Search$`".

Comment: @unor Url I am checking is "/en/search?q=terms#currentYear=2015&content=search ".Is it not working for me because content=search is after # character

Answer (score 0):

The [Yandex Robots.txt analysis](https://webmaster.yandex.com/robots.xml) will block your example if you test for `Search` instead of `search`, as Robots.txt `Disallow` values are case-sensitive.

If your site uses case-insensitive URLs, you might want to use:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*&content=Search$
Disallow: /*&content=search$
# and possibly also =SEARCH, =SEarch, etc.
```

Having said that, I don’t know if Yandex really supports this for URL fragments (it would be unusual, I guess), although their tool gives this impression.